# Como puedo mejorar la velocidad de una funcion en Google Apps Script que trabaja con muchos archivos

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, rendimiento, eficiencia

Tengo una serie de funciones que realizan un inventario de todos los archivos y carpetas de mi drive, en 3 columnas pone la ruta hacia el archivo o carpeta separados por " > ", el nombre de la carpeta o el archivo y la url;

```
`function generarInventario() {
  var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  hojaActiva.clear(); // Limpiar la hoja de cálculo antes de escribir el nuevo inventario
  
  hojaActiva.appendRow(["Ruta", "Nombre del archivo o carpeta", "URL"]); // Encabezados de las columnas
  
  var drive = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  hojaActiva.appendRow(["Mi unidad", "", ""]); // Ruta raíz
  
  listarArchivos(drive, "Mi unidad", hojaActiva);
}

function ordenarAlfabeticamente(array) {
  return array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
  });
}

function listarArchivos(carpeta, ruta, hoja) {
  var carpetas = carpeta.getFolders();
  var carpetasArray = [];
  while (carpetas.hasNext()) {
    carpetasArray.push(carpetas.next().getName());
  }
  carpetasArray = ordenarAlfabeticamente(carpetasArray);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < carpetasArray.length; i++) {
    var nombreCarpeta = carpetasArray[i];
    var subcarpeta = carpeta.getFoldersByName(nombreCarpeta).next();
    hoja.appendRow([ruta, nombreCarpeta, subcarpeta.getUrl()]); // Agregar carpeta con URL
    listarArchivos(subcarpeta, ruta + " > " + nombreCarpeta, hoja);
  }
  
  var archivos = carpeta.getFiles();
  var archivosArray = [];
  while (archivos.hasNext()) {
    archivosArray.push(archivos.next().getName());
  }
  archivosArray = ordenarAlfabeticamente(archivosArray);
  
  for (var j = 0; j < archivosArray.length; j++) {
    var nombreArchivo = archivosArray[j];
    var archivo = carpeta.getFilesByName(nombreArchivo).next();
    hoja.appendRow([ruta, nombreArchivo, archivo.getUrl()]); // Agregar archivo con URL
  }
}
`
```

lo que hago aqui es obtener los datos necesarios realizando bucles para recorrer todas las carpetas y subcarpetas de mi drive y las comparo alfabeticamente para que en el sheets queden ordenadas de arriba a abajo. El script funciona correctamente, empieza a escribir todas las carpetas y archivos de la manera que deseo, pero al ser un drive con muchos archivos, el tiempo de ejecucion que me da Google Apps Script es demasiado corto.

¿Podrian darme alguna idea para mejorar la velocidad de el script?

Comment: Lo que hago para optimizar es colocar los tiempos que se demora la ejecución en varios puntos claves. Con el fin de detectar donde está el o los cuello de botella, y ahí según sea el caso optimizar de alguna manera.  Para esto usas https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance_API

Answer (score 0):

Las llamadas a los servicios de Google Apps Script son lentas por lo que deberías reducirlas lo más posible.

Por ejemplo, en lugar de escribir en una fila en cada iteración, crea un array y escribe varias filas a las vez. Esto es similar a usar procesamiento por lotes (batch).

Deberás monitorear el tiempo de ejecución para evitar que tu script se vea interrumpido por exceder el tiempo máximo de ejecución antes de realizar la escritura.